# Can I get tables of mssql in admin site of django

Tags: django-models

I am using MSSQL, where I have already defined some table so I didn't define anything under models.py file, Is there any way that I get to see all my table in the admin site. ( i successfully connected Django application to MSSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Connect your App with the sql admin account is not secure but if you want the command is

> SHOW TABLES;